# Изменение внешнего вида Hint

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

как изменить внешний вид всплывающей подсказки?

я вывел все страны через objectManager и в зависимости от названия страны раскрасил их в 4 возможных цвета, при этом для каждого цвета вывел свой hintContent. Теперь нужно поменять отображение самой подсказки, условно скруглить углы, прописать паддинги, изменить ширину и высоту. Вот как это сделать не очень понимаю.

Comment: В документации API Яндекс.Карт есть готовый пример изменения хинта - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_hint_layout . Возникли какие-то сложности в его реализации?

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил. Сейчас готово. Спасибо)